# What is stored in IMAP .pst file in MS Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap

What exactly contains .pst file (anything besides emails) which is being created when I set up IMAP account in Outlook?
What is the difference between it and .pst that is being created with POP account?
Is it possible to reduce it's size, mine is more than 10GB?

Comment: It seems to me that your real question is in the last sentence.

Comment: Not only the last one, two first questions are real as well :)

Answer (score 0):

A PST file is short for Personal Store. Outlook uses this file to store your mail, calendar events and other data associated with your account. There is a limit to the size of that file and this limit can be adjusted by altering registry entries:

**for ANSI pst file:**
*value represents file size in bytes*

```
  - REG_DWORD   MaxFileSize         (valid range: 0x00000001 – 0x0000C800)
  - REG_DWORD   WarnFileSize        (valid range: 0x00000000 – 0x0000BE00)
```

**for UNICODE pst file:**
*value represents file size in MegaBytes*

```
  - REG_DWORD   MaxLargeFileSize    (valid range: 0x001F4400 – 0x7C004400)
  - REG_DWORD   WarnLargeFileSize   (valid range: 0x001F4400 – 0x7C004400)
```

Also note that `WarnFileSize` and `WarnLargeFileSize` are used to set the threshold when warning is generated whiile `MaxFileSize` and `MaxLargeFileSize` are the actual limiting values.

The correct location for these registry entries is as follows:

#### Outlook 2013

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\PST
```

#### Outlook 2010

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\PST
```

#### Outlook 2007

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\PST
```

#### Outlook 2003

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Outlook\PST
```

For detailed information please read:

- [How to configure the file size limit for both .pst and .ost file in Outlook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832925)
- [What is stored in a PST file](http://www.ehow.com/about_6587689_stored-pst-file_.html)